# Teardown objects that are created during parametrize method in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a conftest.py file that includes an option for command line, given this option, it creates an N number of the same clients, but with different credentials, as such

```py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--client-type", "--c", action="append", default=[], help="Specify client type(s) for tests")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "clients" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        opt = metafunc.config.getoption("--client-type")
        clients = []
        for client_type in opt:
            if client_type == "default_client":
                client = ClientRequests("A")
                clients.append(client)
            elif client_type == "other_client":
                client = ClientRequests("B")
                clients.append(client)
        metafunc.parametrize("clients", clients)
```

I have a bunch of tests that need to be executed with each of these clients, as such

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected", ["A", "B"])
def test_with_clients(clients, expected):
    assert clients.client == expected
```

I need to run a teardown in order to delete everything related to ClientRequests after the tests are done running. The specific implementation in the conftest.py cannot be changed to a fixture since I need to generate a dynamic list based off a command line option, which will be used to generate the tests.

How do I do this teardown?